Evaluating $\int^\infty_{-\infty} \sin^2(2^x)\cos^2(3^x)\left(4\cos^2(2^x)\left(4\cos^2(3^x)-3\right)^2-1\right)dx$
MIT Integration Bee Finals Tiebreakers Problem 4:
$$\int^\infty_{-\infty} \sin^2(2^x)\cos^2(3^x)\left(4\cos^2(2^x)\left(4\cos^2(3^x)-3\right)^2-1\right)dx$$
Using simple trigonometric simplification, I simplified the integral to:
$$\int^\infty_{-\infty}\sin^2(2^{x+1})\cos^2(3^{x+1})-\sin^2(2^x)\cos^2(3^x) dx$$
What is the method to evaluate this integral? I thought it would be $0$, intuitively, but it turns out that it's not.
The answer given is $\frac{1}{4}$, but Wolfram|Alpha evaluates it as $0.250064$.

Curly braces in integration bees refer to the fractional part function i.e. ${x}=x-\lfloor x \rfloor$. Are you sure it was written this way?

I rolled back the edit for now because of the ambiguity introduced.

Let $\mathcal{I}$ be the integral in question. Then
$$
\begin{align}
\require{cancel}
\mathcal{I}&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\sin^{2}\left(2^{x}\right)\cos^{2}\left(3^{x}\right)\left(4\cos^{2}\left(2^{x}\right)\left(\frac{4\cos^{3}\left(3^{x}\right)-3\cos\left(3^{x}\right)}{\cos\left(3^{x}\right)}\right)^{2}-1\right)dx \\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\sin^{2}\left(2^{x}\right)\cos^{2}\left(3^{x}\right)\left(4\cos^{2}\left(2^{x}\right)\left(\frac{\cos\left(3^{x+1}\right)}{\cos\left(3^{x}\right)}\right)^{2}-1\right)dx \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\sin^{2}\left(2^{x}\right)\cos^{2}\left(3^{x}\right)\left(\frac{\left(2\cos\left(2^{x}\right)\sin\left(2^{x}\right)\right)^{2}}{\sin^{2}\left(2^{x}\right)}\cdot\frac{\cos^{2}\left(3^{x+1}\right)}{\cos^{2}\left(3^{x}\right)}-1\right)dx \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\sin^{2}\left(2^{x+1}\right)\cos^{2}\left(3^{x+1}\right)-\sin^{2}\left(2^{x}\right)\cos^{2}\left(3^{x}\right)\right)dx \\
&= \lim_{a\to\infty}\int_{-a}^{a}\left(\sin^{2}\left(2^{x+1}\right)\cos^{2}\left(3^{x+1}\right)-\sin^{2}\left(2^{x}\right)\cos^{2}\left(3^{x}\right)\right)dx \\
&= \lim_{a\to\infty}\left(\int_{-a}^{a}\sin^{2}\left(2^{x+1}\right)\cos^{2}\left(3^{x+1}\right)\,dx-\int_{-a}^{a}\sin^{2}\left(2^{x}\right)\cos^{2}\left(3^{x}\right)\,dx\right) \\
&= \lim_{a\to\infty}\left(\underbrace{\int_{1-a}^{1+a}\sin^{2}\left(2^{x}\right)\cos^{2}\left(3^{x}\right)\,dx}_{x+1\,\mapsto \,x}-\int_{-a}^{a}\sin^{2}\left(2^{x}\right)\cos^{2}\left(3^{x}\right)\,dx\right) \\
&= \lim_{a\to\infty}\left(\int_{a}^{1+a}\sin^{2}\left(2^{x}\right)\cos^{2}\left(3^{x}\right)\,dx+\bcancel{\int_{1-a}^{a}\sin^{2}\left(2^{x}\right)\cos^{2}\left(3^{x}\right)\,dx}-\int_{-a}^{1-a}\sin^{2}\left(2^{x}\right)\cos^{2}\left(3^{x}\right)\,dx-\bcancel{\int_{1-a}^{a}\sin^{2}\left(2^{x}\right)\cos^{2}\left(3^{x}\right)\,dx}\right) \\
&= \lim_{a\to\infty}\int_{a}^{1+a}\sin^{2}\left(2^{x}\right)\cos^{2}\left(3^{x}\right)\,dx-\lim_{a\to\infty}\int_{-a}^{1-a}\sin^{2}\left(2^{x}\right)\cos^{2}\left(3^{x}\right)\,dx\,. \\
\end{align} 
$$
First, we'll prove that the second integral goes to $0$ as $a\to\infty$. Let $x=v-a$ so that $dx=dv$. Then we have
$$
\int_{0}^{1}\lim_{a\to\infty}\sin^{2}\left(2^{v}2^{-a}\right)\cos^{2}\left(3^{v}3^{-a}\right)\,dv = \int_{0}^{1}0\cdot1\,dv = 0\,.
$$
For the first integral, we use some trig identities/formulas as follows:
$$
\begin{align}
\require{cancel}
\mathcal{I}&=\lim_{a\to\infty}\int_{a}^{1+a}\sin^{2}\left(2^{x}\right)\cos^{2}\left(3^{x}\right)\,dx-\cancelto{\,0}{\lim_{a\to\infty}\int_{-a}^{1-a}\sin^{2}\left(2^{x}\right)\cos^{2}\left(3^{x}\right)\,dx} \\
&= \lim_{a\to\infty}\int_{a}^{a+1}\frac{1-\cos\left(2^{x+1}\right)}{2}\cdot\frac{\cos\left(2\cdot3^{x}\right)+1}{2}\,dx \\
&= \lim_{a\to\infty}\int_{a}^{a+1}\frac{1-\cos\left(2^{x+1}\right)+\cos\left(2\cdot3^{x}\right)-\cos\left(2^{x+1}\right)\cos\left(2\cdot3^{x}\right)}{4}\,dx \\
&= \lim_{a\to\infty}\int_{a}^{a+1}\frac{1}{4}\,dx-\frac{1}{4}\lim_{a\to\infty}\int_{a}^{a+1}\cos\left(2^{x+1}\right)\,dx+\frac{1}{4}\lim_{a\to\infty}\int_{a}^{a+1}\cos\left(2\cdot3^{x}\right)\,dx \\
&\,\,\,\,\,\,-\frac{1}{8}\lim_{a\to\infty}\int_{a}^{a+1}\cos\left(2\cdot3^{x}+2^{x+1}\right)\,dx-\frac{1}{8}\lim_{a\to\infty}\int_{a}^{a+1}\cos\left(2\cdot3^{x}-2^{x+1}\right)\,dx\,. \\
\end{align}
$$
The first integral is easy to solve. For the other ones, notice that $2^{x+1}$, $2\cdot3^{x}$, $2\cdot3^{x}+2^{x+1}$, and $2\cdot3^{x}-2^{x+1}$ are convex and increasing when $x$ is positive with unbounded derivatives. We introduce a general function $f$ that has these properties. Let $c$ be a positive real number and $c<a$ so that
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{a\to\infty}\int_{a}^{a+1}\cos\left(f\left(x\right)\right)\,dx&=\lim_{a\to\infty}\left(\int_{c}^{a+1}\cos\left(f\left(x\right)\right)\,dx-\int_{c}^{a}\cos\left(f\left(x\right)\right)\,dx\right) \\
&= \int_{c}^{\infty}\cos\left(f\left(x\right)\right)\,dx - \int_{c}^{\infty}\cos\left(f\left(x\right)\right)\,dx \\
&= 0\,.
\end{align}
$$
For this to make sense, we will prove the improper integrals converge in this next section.

Let $c\in\mathbb{R}$ and $f:[c,\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be an increasing, convex, and differentiable function such that $f'(x) \to \infty$ as $x\to\infty$. Then $\int_{c}^{\infty}\cos{(f(x))}\,dx$ converges.
Proof. Let $u=f(x)$ so that $f^{-1}(u)=x$ and $dx=\frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(u))}du$. Note that strictly monotone functions have an inverse because they are guaranteed to have a one-to-one mapping from their range to their domain. Then
$$
\int_{c}^{\infty}\cos\left(f\left(x\right)\right)\,dx = \int_{f\left(c\right)}^{f\left(\infty\right)}\frac{\cos u}{f'\left(f^{-1}(u\right))}\,du
$$
The upper bound $f(\infty)$ equals $\infty$ since
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x)=\infty \implies \lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty\,.
$$

To prove this implication, assume by way of contradiction that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x)=\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)\neq\infty$. Since $f$ is bounded, there exists some $M>0$ such that $|f(x)|<M$. For all positive integers $n$, employing the Mean Value Theorem to $f$ for $[n,n+1]$ yields
$$
f'(c_n)=\frac{f(n+1)-f(n)}{n+1-n}=f(n+1)-f(n)
$$
where $c_n\in(n,n+1)$. If $n\to\infty$ then $c_n\to\infty$. Since we know $\lim_{n\to\infty}f'(n)=\infty$, we get
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}f'(c_n)=\infty\,. \tag{1}
$$
However,
$$
|f'(c_n)|=|f(n+1)-f(n)|\leq|f(n+1)|+|f(n)|\leq M+M=2M\,.
$$
This proves the sequence $f'(c_n)$ is bounded, contradicting $(1)$.

The integral becomes
$$
\int_{f\left(c\right)}^{f\left(\infty\right)}\frac{\cos u}{f'\left(f^{-1}(u\right))}\,du = \int_{f\left(c\right)}^{\infty}\frac{\cos u}{f'\left(f^{-1}(u\right))}\,du\,.
$$
It converges by Dirichlet's Test for Improper Integrals (Thereom 17.5). To show this:

We know $\cos u$ is continuous everywhere and $\left|\int_{f(c)}^u \cos t \,dt\right|$ is bounded.
We see $\frac{1}{f'\left(f^{-1}\left(u\right)\right)}$ is monotonically decreasing to $0$ because $f'$ is increasing due to $f$ being convex. This stems from the statement "$f$ is convex $\iff$ $f'$ is monotonically increasing" which we may read here.

Therefore, $\int_{c}^{\infty}\cos{(f(x))}\,dx$ converges. $\blacksquare$

Finally going back to $\mathcal{I}$, we get
$$
\mathcal{I}=\lim_{a\to\infty}\int_{a}^{a+1}\frac{1}{4}dx-\frac{1}{4}\cdot0+\frac{1}{4}\cdot0-\frac{1}{8}\cdot0-\frac{1}{8}\cdot0 = \lim_{a\to\infty}\left(\frac{a+1}{4}-\frac{a}{4}\right) = \frac{1}{4}\,.
$$
In conclusion,
$$
\bbox[13px,#fefbf0,border:5px ridge #b49400]{\int^\infty_{-\infty} \sin^2(2^x)\cos^2(3^x)\left(4\cos^2(2^x)\left(4\cos^2(3^x)-3\right)^2-1\right)\,dx = \frac{1}{4}}
$$
and we're done!

Small note: You've technically calculated the Cauchy principal value, not the improper integral. $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)dx = \lim_{a \to \infty} \int_{-a}^a f(x)dx$ only when the left-hand side converges, which you have not shown in your solution. Since it's an integration bee, they may pre-suppose convergence, however, so it may be a non-issue here.

Why is a $u = x + 1$ substitution invalid?

@infinitylord Thanks for pointing it out. I forgot about the Cauchy principal value and naively assumed that the integral converges since integration bees always assume improper integrals converge to a real number. If I find a way to prove that the improper integral converges or diverges then I'll edit my answer to include the proof.

@Infiniticity That substitution is valid when you're working with the Cauchy principal value because you're making the substitution on the interval $[-a,a]$ without taking into account the limits until the end of the solution, so the u-substitution theorem applies here. I wrote $x+1\mapsto x$ which basically means $u=x+1$. If I'm able to prove the proposed integral diverges then I have to make some small changes which would be adding $\operatorname{PV}$ at the beginning and adding an addendum proving why the proposed integral diverges but the Cauchy principal value equals $1/4$.

Wonderful!+1). I think we should have a simpler solution.

$$
\int^\infty_{-\infty} \sin^{2}\left(2^{x}\right)\cos^2(3^x)\left\{4\cos^2(2^x)\left[4\cos^2(3^x)-3\right]^2-1\right\}dx
$$
$$
=\int^\infty_{-\infty} 4\sin^{2}\left(2^{x}\right)\cos^2(2^x)\left[4\cos^3(3^x)-3\cos(3^x)\right]^2dx-\int^\infty_{-\infty} \sin^{2}\left(2^{x}\right)\cos^2(3^x)dx
$$
$$
=\int^\infty_{-\infty} \sin^{2}\left(2^{x+1}\right)\cos^2(3^{x+1})dx-\int^\infty_{-\infty} \sin^{2}\left(2^{x}\right)\cos^2(3^x)dx
$$
This is as you found. Now substitute $x$ for $x+1$ in the first integral to get zero as the result! Sadly, although Wolfram Alpha gives values to each, I don't believe the two integrals do converge separately, so Wolfram Alpha is wrong. Each integrand is positive, and I see no reason why it would tend to zero. In fact, the argument I give below suggests that the average value of the integrand will be close to $\frac{1}{4}$ for large $x$.
So consider $$
\int^N_{-M} \sin^{2}\left(2^{x}\right)\cos^2(3^x)\left\{4\cos^2(2^x)\left[4\cos^2(3^x)-3\right]^2-1\right\}dx
$$
$$=\int^N_{-M} \sin^{2}\left(2^{x+1}\right)\cos^2(3^{x+1})dx-\int^N_{-M} \sin^{2}\left(2^{x}\right)\cos^2(3^x)dx$$
$$=\int^{N+1}_{-(M-1)} \sin^{2}\left(2^{x}\right)\cos^2(3^{x})dx-\int^N_{-M} \sin^{2}\left(2^{x}\right)\cos^2(3^x)dx$$
$$=\int^{N+1}_{N} \sin^{2}\left(2^{x}\right)\cos^2(3^{x})dx-\int^{-M}_{-(M-1)} \sin^{2}\left(2^{x}\right)\cos^2(3^x)dx.$$
The second integral will tend to zero as $M \to \infty$. In the first integral, the $\cos^2$ factor will cycle many, many times for each cycle of the $\sin^2$ factor, so we can average over it; also, for large $x$, the $3^x$ factor will be close to linear over each cycle, so we would expect the average to be no different from that of $\cos^2$, which is $\frac{1}{2}$. So $$\int^{N+1}_{N} \sin^{2}\left(2^{x}\right)\cos^2(3^{x})dx \approx \int^{N+1}_{N} \frac{1}{2}\sin^{2}\left(2^{x}\right)dx$$ for large $N$. Now we can apply the argument again: $$\int^{N+1}_{N} \frac{1}{2}\sin^{2}\left(2^{x}\right)dx \approx \int^{N+1}_{N} \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2}dx = \frac{1}{4}$$ for large $N$.
This is a very hand-wavy argument, and I don't know how to make it less informal. Does it 'explain' the result? Can anyone make it rigorous?
Incidentally, it also suggests why the substitution argument is invalid - the "extra $\frac{1}{4}$" does not disappear as the upper limit tends to infinity.

I'm not sure that I'm convinced by my own answer. Do the two integrals converge separately?

Yes they do ${}$

@mcd If we substitute $x+1$ with $x$, wouldn't the integrals become equal?

@Infiniticity Yes, so this would give zero as the result of the original integral. That's why I don't think my argument is correct.

@mcd According to Wolfram|Alpha, the two integrals do converge separately, here and here.

@Infiniticity. I hadn't expected that, though my hand-wavy argument suggests why the substitution is invalid - the "extra $\frac{1}{4}$" in the first integral occurs "at infinity". I've amended my answer to take account of that.

You can show that it's equal to $\lim_{N\to\infty}\int_{N}^{3N}\frac{\cos^2(x)}{x\ln(3)}\sin^2\left(x^{\log_{3}(2)}\right)dx=\lim_{N\to\infty}\int_{N}^{2N}\frac{\sin^2(x)}{x\ln(2)}\cos^2\left(x^{\log_{2}(3)}\right)dx$, although I'm not sure how much this helps.

The answer is $\frac{1}{4}$. MIT did not make a mistake, but I wonder if there's some sneaky and clever way to solve the integral since these MIT integration bees are known for that. I won't be able to post an answer anytime soon since the proof I wrote in my notebook took a million years to write, but I'll post an answer sometime early next year trying to make it as rigorous as possible.

@Accelerator I'm not questioning the answer to the MIT question, which requires the improper integral of the difference; I'm just not sure that it makes sense to equate this to the difference of the two improper integrals.

@Infiniticity I've changed my mind about the separate convergence of the integrals - see my amended answer. I think Wolfram Alpha is wrong.

@mcd Yes, Wolfram|Alpha is wrong, since definite integrals on smaller finite intervals turn out to be greater than the infinite integral which is obviously impossible.
